$\operatorname{End}_S(M \otimes_R S) \cong \operatorname{End}_R(M) \otimes_R S$?
Let $R$ and $S$ be commutative rings with unity. Let $f: R \to S$ be a ring homomorphism. Let $M$ be an $R$-module. Do we have
$$
\operatorname{End}_S(M \otimes_R S) \cong \operatorname{End}_R(M) \otimes_R S
$$
as $S$-algebras?

No, not necessarily. What you'd like to do is argue that the universal property of the tensor product allows you to identify
$$\text{End}_S(M \otimes_R S) \cong \text{Hom}_R(M, M \otimes_R S)$$
and then you'd like to commute the hom and the tensor, but this is not generally possible (see this answer for some discussion). Basically the problem is that $\text{Hom}_R(M, -)$ is a kind of limit while $(-) \otimes_R S$ is a kind of colimit. Sufficient conditions that allow us to do this are (everything is as modules over $R$)

$M$ is finitely generated projective,
$M$ is finitely presented and $S$ is flat,
$M$ is projective and $S$ is finitely presented, or
$S$ is finitely generated projective.

So a counterexample cannot fall under any of these cases. We will take $M$ and $S$ to both be infinitely generated.
Specifically, take $R = \mathbb{Z}, S = \mathbb{Q}$, and $M = \bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}$ to be the free abelian group on countably many generators. (Note that $M$ is projective and $S$ is flat.) Then $M \otimes \mathbb{Q} \cong \bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Q}$ has endomorphism ring
$$\text{End}_{\mathbb{Q}}(M \otimes \mathbb{Q}) \cong M_{\infty}(\mathbb{Q})$$
(the ring of column-finite matrices over $\mathbb{Q}$), but
$$\text{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M) \otimes \mathbb{Q} \cong M_{\infty}(\mathbb{Z}) \otimes \mathbb{Q}$$
is the rationalization of the ring of column-finite matrices over $\mathbb{Z}$. There is a natural map from the second ring to the first ring and it is injective but not surjective: its image consists of elements of $M_{\infty}(\mathbb{Q})$ whose entries can all be put under a common denominator, so it does not contain, for example, the diagonal matrix with entries $\frac{1}{n}, n \in \mathbb{N}$.
A useful special case is that this is true if $R, S$ are both fields and $f : R \to S$ is a finite extension. In this case $S$ is finitely generated projective. In particular it is true if $R = \mathbb{R}, S = \mathbb{C}$, which can be used to deduce some useful facts about the relationship between representation theory of groups and Lie algebras over $\mathbb{R}$ and over $\mathbb{C}$.

Very beautiful answer. Thanks for sharing this very memorable (counter)example.
